# Document libraries: Can you HIDE columns in a parent directory but SHOW them in children directories?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-library

The parent directory of my document library contains folders. When I get into one of these folders, I want to be able to see the columns I've created, but NOT see them when I'm in the parent directory.

I've looked in the library settings but can't seem to find anything about this.

Is there a way to do this out-of-the-box in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using **classic experience** for the document library.
We can decide which columns to display on separate list views:

1. Go to the list view you want to show on the parent directory (or the default list view), navigate to *Edit View* > *Folders* > **Show this view: In the top-level folder**. Click OK.
2. Create a new standard view and modify the columns that you want to show children directories, navigate to *Edit View* > *Folders* > **Show this view: In folders of content type: Folder**. Click OK.

Now when you access the parent directory and the children directories, different list views will display accordingly.

Note that this feature is not supported in modern experience for the time being.

Reference: [Harness SharePoint Library and Folder Default Views to build more appealing solutions.](https://camerondwyer.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/)

Comment: Hi ChelseaMSFT and thanks for your help. Your information solved my issue.

Comment: @rizingfenix Glad to know. Would you please give it a vote or accept it as answer if you find the reply helpful? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well. Thanks.